# Radio button displaying "on" instead of the actual value

Tags: php, html

I'm confused as to why the actual value of my radio button isn't displaying, it's instead outputting "on"..here's my code:

**index.php**

```
<input type="radio" name="p1rad" value = "1st" checked ><font class = "rad" >1st</font>
<input type="radio" name="p1rad" value = "2nd"><font class = "rad" >2nd</font>
<input type="radio" name="p1rad" value = "Summer"><font class = "rad" >Summer</font><br>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['semester'] = $_POST['p1rad']; 
?>
```

**page3.php**

```
   <?php session_start();
   <td><?php echo "<font>Name: </font>".$_SESSION['name']; ?></td><br>
   <td><?php echo "<font>SN: </font>".$_SESSION['studentNo']; ?></td> <br>
   <td><?php echo "<font>Sem: </font>".$_SESSION['semester']; ?></td>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: do a `print_r()` on `$_POST` to see the structure. That will take out all guess work in your debugging.

Comment: it displays "1" instead...

Comment: update your question with the output from print_r() that would be great.